# Can I use another way to get the time from C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
string GetTime()
{
    time_t Timev;
    struct tm * TimeInformation;
    time(&(time_t)Timev);
    (tm*)TimeInformation = localtime(&(time_t)Timev);
    char Timec[100];
    strftime((char*)Timec, 100, "[%X]:", (tm*)TimeInformation);
    string GetTimex((char*)Timec);
    return GetTimex;
};
```

Why do I get the warning

> warning C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Is there any other way to get time in format [Hour:Minutes:Second], and is it possible to shorten the code like `int abc; abc=123` to `int abc{123}`?

Comment: C-style casts are not recommended in C++.  Every one of those six should be superfluous.  The `localtime()` function is not thread-safe; it returns a pointer to static data.  Using `localtime_s()` as the error suggests avoids that problem; you provide the storage for the result.  You could use `time_t Timev = time(0); struct tm *TimeInformation = localtime(&Timev);` and you should be able to avoid the named string variable too.

Comment: Why the crazy cast of `Timev` from `time_t` to `time_t` and of `Timec` from `char[]` to `char*`?  That really makes your code hard to read!  Also, there's no `GetTimex()` in any standard library header, so you might want to explain what that is.

Comment: @TobySpeight `GetTimex` is a badly-named `std::string` with a weird initialization syntax.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin - I think I was thrown by the `Get...` at the front of the name!  `return Timec;` would have been much clearer.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, from what you said "time_t to time_t" i just wanted to specific the type of the variable ... is it wrong ? i learning C++ myself dont know much about it ... && sry for any trouble =3

Comment: Casts are dangerous, and should be used as sparingly as possible.  When you write a cast, you're reducing your compiler's ability to tell you about problems in your code - instead of an error, you would quietly get wrong behaviour.  All the type casts in your example are unnecessary; your code will be both clearer and more robust if you avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to install Howard Hinnant's free, open-source [tz library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), then `GetTime()` can be simplified down to:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <string>

std::string
GetTime()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    return format("[%X]:", make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now()));
}
```

This just output for me:

```
[10:42:32]:
```

Here are the [installation directions](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation) (including for Windows).

Comment: Just realised that my edit makes it look like you refer to yourself in the third person - sorry about that; I just wanted to ease the recognition for anyone who's already using (or avoiding) your library.  P.S. is there an RFP for Debian, so it's more easily (and safely) usable?

Comment: @TobySpeight:  Not a problem.  I reviewed your edit, and I'm fine with it, thanks.  I've used the same formulation myself.  Someone mentioned to me that they were working on a Debian package, but I don't know the status of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // std::put_time
#include <ctime>   // std::localtime, std::time, std::time_t, std::gmtime

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "UTC:   " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%X") << '\n';
    std::cout << "local: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%X") << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
UTC:   14:18:02
local: 14:18:02
```

And your `GetTime` would then be:

```
std::string GetTime()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "[%X]");
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: You could use that code, but it doesn't address the underlying issue that `std::localtime()` returns static storage that may be modified by other threads concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

localtime has an internal storage that is static, which means it is not threadsafe. Most systems do have threadsafe alternatives, but they are not part of the standard library. For example, Windows has localtime_s and Linux/Posix has localtime_r.
The std library functions std::strftime and std::put_time could be a safer alternative, like explained in [this article](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/exploring-c11-part-2-localtime-and-time-again/)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `std::localtime()` (when it suceeds) is a

> pointer to a static internal `std::tm` object

Further,

> The structure may be shared between `std::gmtime`, `std::localtime`, and `std::ctime`, and may be overwritten on each invocation.

(*from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)*)

This means that if you're using any of these functions in other threads, you may have a data race.  If you're sure that no other threads are using any of those functions (perhaps because your program is single-threaded), then you may safely ignore the warning.

It appears that your compiler is recommending you use its implementation-defined alternative - whether you do is up to you, but you might want to consider isolating any platform-dependency you then introduce.